# Removing space after last character in a matrix

Tags: python

```
r=0
c=0
r, c = input().split()
a = int(r)
b = int(c)
mat = []
x=1
y=0
for i in range(a):
    l=[]
    for j in range(b):
        l.append(x)
        x += 1
    mat.append(l)
for i in range(a):
    for j in range(b):
        print(mat[i][j],end=(" "))
    if y<a-1:

        print()
    y+=1
```

So, here I used if for removing '\n' from the last character of the output, and hence I want to know how to remove the very last space after the last character.(The online compiler is very strict and hence blocking my code)

Comment: Please be very precise about what you need. I'm assuming you want no space at end of each line and a newline at each line? `for i in range(a):
    print(" ".join([str(x) for x in mat[i]]))` or similar should work in place of your last loop. What online judge are you using (link to the problem)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `for` loop to print you can do this with `' '.join()`, e.g.:

```
for i in range(a):
    print(' '.join(str(n) for n in mat[i]))
```

You can also do this by iterating directly over `mat`:

```
for row in mat:
    print(' '.join(str(n) for n in row))
```

This way there is no trailing space and it will have a newline for each row.

Comment: Thanks man for your help. It was my first time trying stackoverflow and didn't to get the help this quick, thanks again for the help. :)